# Estoy implementando esta consulta correctamente con PHP?

Tags: php, plsql

Estoy implementando esta consulta correctamente con PHP?

Ya he revisado los datos de conexión y están correctos, planteo mi consulta en base a la documentación oficial de PHP, sin embargo no obtengo el resultado esperado, de antemano agradezco tu apoyo.

Consulta que me muestra resultados directamente en consola:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
DECLARE 
num_N_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER;
num_N_OVERDRAFT NUMBER;
dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END    DATE;
BEGIN
SI_USERS_PKG_S.GET_ACCOUNT_CREDIT(
num_N_ACCOUNT_ID => 148664791,
num_N_OVERDRAFT => num_N_OVERDRAFT,
dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END => dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END
);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num_N_OVERDRAFT);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END);
END;
```

Implementada con PHP

```
$sql="  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
    DECLARE 
    num_N_ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER;
    num_N_OVERDRAFT NUMBER;
    dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END DATE;
    BEGIN
    SI_USERS_PKG_S.GET_ACCOUNT_CREDIT(
    :num_N_ACCOUNT_ID,
    :num_N_OVERDRAFT,
    :dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END
    );
    END;";
$account    = 148664791;
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':num_N_ACCOUNT_ID', $account);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':num_N_OVERDRAFT', $cantidad,20);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':dt_D_OVERDRAFT_END', $fecha,20);
oci_execute($stid);
print "$cantidad\n";
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te recomiendo pasarte por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Las preguntas tienen que estar acotadas. Añade toda la información que permita simplificar el trabajo de aquel que te intenta ayudar. Por ejemplo ¿Qué le pasa a tu código? ¿Se supone que tenemos que intuir lo que le pasa? ¿Qué has intentado para solucionarlo?

Comment: No lo añadas como un comentario. Edita la pregunta y añade ahí todo lo necesario para que tu pregunta quede bien detallada. Un saludo.

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: No veo la variable $conn. Supongo que no incluiste todo el código.

Comment: PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-00922:

Comment: Es el error mostrado en el archivo error.log

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la sentencia SQL como bien te marca el error. Si buscas el error de ORA por google encontramos esto

> Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
>
> Causa: An invalid option was specified in defining a column or storage
>   clause. The valid option in specifying a column is NOT NULL to specify
>   that the column cannot contain any NULL values. Only constraints may
>   follow the datatype. Specifying a maximum length on a DATE or LONG
>   datatype also causes this error.
>
> Acción: Correct the syntax. Remove the erroneous option or length
>   specification from the column or storage specification. `

Revisa y encuentra especificación errónea de datos (Number, String, etc) o longitud de la columna o especificación de almacenamiento.

```
create table T_PRODUCTOS (
  numproduct number,  <-- tipo de dato
  desproduct varchar2(10)  <-- tipo de dato y tamaño de caracteres
)
```

Comment: El problema esta en tu base de datos. Tu sabras que longitud le has dado a las columnas o que tipo de dato tiene cada Atributo.